# How to find whether the parameter has set on rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

Is there any method that developers can use to check whether particular parameter is set or not in rails controller ??

Comment: Please explain in details so that one able to answer........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want to archive?

```
 if parmas[:my_params]
   #param is set, do your stuff
 else
   #it's not set, do another stuff
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# root level parameter
params[:search_key].present?
```